# SSH2 Connect Issues

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I am using Laravel framework with homestead. (Latest Version) and i am trying to use ssh2_connect. I have installed the extension

```
sudo apt install php-ssh2
```

and i have tested that its working

```
php -m |grep ssh2
```

i am seeing

```
ssh2
```

i am assuming that this is correct but when i try and make a connection i get the following error.

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ssh2_connect()
```

This is the code i am executing

```
 $connection = ssh2_connect($request->sever_ip, 2222);
    if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
```

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: $connection = ssh2_connect($request->sever_ip, 2222);
        if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');

Comment: Add it in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: just updated.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are in the namespace of the `Controllers` you might need to use:

```
$connection = \ssh2_connect($request->sever_ip, 2222);
if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
```

Comment: It should work without backslash. Per the documentation: `For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php It's only for globlal classes that you need the backslash.

Comment: @this.lau_ I agree with you, however I've seen some weird things related to namespaces. If the above doesn't work it is probably ssh2 isn't loaded by the php (apache restart might be needed here).

Comment: Yes i think the function is just not loaded properly. Maybe it's setup for the php command line but not Apache.

Comment: i have fixed it after a `vagrant provision` this seem to get it all working.